# Trying to change the way date time model is stored

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting out with Django and Python and right now the way I store the date published is like this.

```
models.py
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Published')

views.py
def home(request):
    today = Premium.objects.latest('pub_date')
    todays_date = today.pub_date.date()
    etc...
```

I need the date to be April 3, 2015 format so thats why I go about it like that.  Im wondering if there is a way to change the model and the way things are stored into the DB so that I dont have to run a pub_date.date() every time I want to call the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `DateTimeField` if you just want to store the date. Use `DateField` instead.